Polynomial of a ring is nilpotent if all of its coefficients are nilpotent?
Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative) and $R[x]$ its polynomial ring. Suppose $f(x)\in R[x]$ is such that $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdot\cdot\cdot + a_nx^n$. My question is if $a_i$ is nilpotent for each $i$, then is it true that $f(x)$ is nilpotent?
My attempt: First, let us try for one degree polynomial. Take $f(x)=a_0+a_1x$. Let us square it, $(f(x))^2=a_0^2+(a_0a_1+a_1a_0)x+a_1^2x^2$. Here for some power $a_0$ and $a_1$ will be zero, but we can't say about $a_0a_1$ and $a_1a_0$.

If $R$ is not commutative, then it need not be true. Take the ring of matrices of size $2$, and $a_0=E_{12}$, $a_1=E_{21}$. Then $a_0a_1=E_{11}$ is not nilpotent. This is exactly what you wrote. So the theorem is meant for a commutative ring $R$, see the duplicate.

I think this is not a duplicate, as OP noted that the ring is noncommutative, the moderators should take a closer look.
For a concrete example, consider $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \ x & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{Mat}{2}(\mathbb Z)[x]$, we have $a_0 = E{1, 2}, a_1 = E_{2, 1}$, and the matrix is not nilpotent (its $2 n$-th power is $\begin{bmatrix} x^n & 0 \ 0 & x^n \end{bmatrix}$).
Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67095.
